# how to find correlation between two different OTUs tables?

Tags: r, correlation

I'm newbie in statistic and need help...I have two OTUs tables from the same study, which have different length of OTU column:

one for Bateria (1500+ OTUs)

```
otu G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6  G7  G8  G9  G10 G11 G12 G13
Otu001  526 708 1094    368 828 0   0   0   202 1713    1062    481 0
Otu002  181 51  47  575 769 7   0   24  75  64  47  293 316
Otu003  355 245 254 191 1   0   186 0   179 87  25  60  23
Otu004  434 251 114 202 0   0   0   0   0   5   10  5   0
Otu005  100 57  324 469 818 0   0   0   30  94  59  314 144
Otu006  4   1   1   868 481 4   155 0   0   0   6   19  2
Otu007  1   2   5   2   7   0   0   0   0   8   5   0   0
Otu008  215 3   32  42  0   1   71  0   1233    24  8   115 9
Otu009  109 129 92  113 0   0   0   0   7   9   25  0   2
Otu010  160 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   106 0   0   24  31
```

and one for Eukaryotes (250+ OTUs)

```
otu G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6  G7  G8  G9  G10 G11 G12 G13
Otu0001 2903    498 1625    16  0   4   0   0   5305    9614    4003    22  3
Otu0002 417 292 303 353 1843    3731    1906    3070    10  20  7   467 59
Otu0003 0   0   1   0   27  1   182 59  0   18  27  874 4379
Otu0004 156 131 160 203 977 2372    1093    1166    1   7   6   369 74
Otu0005 181 56  118 319 510 1805    517 717 7   23  6   212 37
Otu0006 72  18  138 134 118 181 44  39  23  54  20  869 19
Otu0007 79  15  1015    24  0   0   14  0   113 513 509 4   9
Otu0008 342 51  897 659 393 0   294 27  132 353 139 296 196
Otu0009 75  48  45  100 229 624 353 463 1   5   3   106 18
Otu0010 34  31  17  27  190 336 410 358 2   1   4   178 14
```

How can I estimate correlation between OTUs for those both matrices?

I found one solution, but I do not know how to interpret the result. Here is it in R code:

```
library(psych)
#take a top 100 OTUs from each table
data_V23<-read.table("BV23_100otu.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
data_E3<-read.table("E3_100otu.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
corr.test(t(data_V23), t(data_E3), use = "pairwise",method="pearson",adjust="holm", alpha=.05,ci=TRUE)
```

here is the part of result:

```
        Otu001 Otu002 Otu003 Otu004 Otu005 Otu006 Otu007 Otu008 Otu009 Otu010 Otu011 Otu012 Otu013 Otu014 Otu015 Otu016 Otu017 Otu018 Otu019
Otu0001   0.67  -0.31   0.12  -0.05  -0.27  -0.30   0.52   0.36  -0.08   0.24   0.18  -0.38   0.37   0.56  -0.19   0.01   0.44  -0.05   0.05
Otu0002  -0.50  -0.10  -0.44  -0.30  -0.09   0.01  -0.28  -0.27  -0.40  -0.30  -0.40   0.18  -0.44  -0.37   0.22  -0.25  -0.43  -0.34  -0.30
Otu0003  -0.32   0.18  -0.29  -0.22  -0.03  -0.16  -0.29  -0.12  -0.26   0.03  -0.26   0.29  -0.27  -0.15  -0.06  -0.19  -0.22  -0.20  -0.20
Otu0004  -0.49  -0.09  -0.44  -0.32  -0.07   0.02  -0.28  -0.26  -0.41  -0.31  -0.41   0.26  -0.44  -0.36   0.25  -0.26  -0.42  -0.33  -0.32
Otu0005  -0.47  -0.09  -0.39  -0.22  -0.09   0.05  -0.29  -0.24  -0.31  -0.25  -0.31   0.15  -0.34  -0.33   0.10  -0.18  -0.32  -0.19  -0.29
Otu0006  -0.03   0.20  -0.16  -0.14   0.27  -0.01  -0.20  -0.08  -0.18  -0.05  -0.14   0.48  -0.14  -0.23  -0.12  -0.06  -0.21   0.01  -0.22
Otu0007   0.70  -0.32   0.21  -0.03   0.01  -0.25   0.60  -0.08   0.20  -0.17   0.54  -0.34   0.79   0.15  -0.16   0.44   0.30   0.09  -0.02
Otu0008   0.40   0.36   0.43   0.25   0.57   0.46   0.42  -0.15   0.42  -0.08   0.67  -0.08   0.75  -0.19   0.00   0.66   0.12   0.61  -0.15
Otu0009  -0.55  -0.15  -0.40  -0.28  -0.15   0.02  -0.36  -0.27  -0.38  -0.30  -0.39   0.27  -0.44  -0.38   0.29  -0.24  -0.41  -0.29  -0.31
Otu0010  -0.56  -0.14  -0.37  -0.38  -0.14  -0.01  -0.39  -0.25  -0.50  -0.32  -0.49   0.55  -0.54  -0.39   0.56  -0.33  -0.48  -0.40  -0.36
```

Comment: You may want to tag your question with the appropriate language. Alternatively, you may want to ask this at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Evert yeh, thanks! missed "r"-tag.I'll Try to aks at datascience.stackexchange.com, thanks for advise!